# Algorithm to evaluate matrix expression $x^T A^{-1} x$,

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

my program evaluates a lot of expressions like this:
$x^T A^{-1} x$ (some loglikelihood optimization), where $A$ is symmetric, positive definite matrix and $x$ is vector. I do it only once for a given $A$ and given  $x$.

Is there a faster way to do this, than just finding inverted matrix?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you perform this calculation multiple times with the same $A$ and different values of $x$?

Comment: No, I wrote that I use each A only once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Computing $A^{-1}x$ is much faster, in general, than finding $A^{-1}$ and multiplying by $x$. Matlab's `A\x` does this faster computation for you, if you happen to be using it.

Comment: Thanks. I googled a little, and found that I can reformulate $A^{-1} x=b$ as linear equation, $Ab = x$ which can be solved for $b$ more efficiently, especially in symmetric case (Cholesky decomp.). This will do for me

Comment: @Krystian, that's the right way: decompose $\mathbf A$ with Cholesky, and use the decomposition to compute $\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf x$, and take the dot product of that with $\mathbf x$.

Comment: A slightly more efficient calculation: once you have $A = LL^T$, compute $x^TAx = \|(L^{-1})^Tx\|^2$